# Cannot read property 'navigate' of undefined - React Native

Tags: react-native, navigation

I am new at React-Native. I just keep getting same error that "Cannot read property 'navigate' of undefined". Here is the sample code

```
export default class Form extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.loginHandler = this.loginHandler.bind(this);
        this.navigate  = this.props.navigation;
        this.successCallback = this.successCallback.bind(this);
        this.state = {
            email: '',
            password: '',
        }
    }

    // TODO - Login Authentication
    loginHandler() {
        var loginUrl = 'someURL';
        fetch(loginUrl, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                Accept: 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                username: this.state.email,
                password: this.state.password
            }),
        })
            .then(response => { return response.json(); })
            .then(responseData => { return responseData; })
            .then((responseData) => {
                this.successCallback(responseData.token)
            })
            .catch((err) => { console.log(err); });

    }

    successCallback(token) {
        if (token === undefined)
            alert("Email or password is incorrect !");
        else {
            this.props.navigation.navigate('User', {tokenFromUser: token});
        }
```

}

In successCallback function, if token is generated it means login credentials are correct so it should navigate to UserScreen with paremeter 'token'. Can anyone help me ?

Here is the how I call loginHandler function

```
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={this.loginHandler} >
            <Image source={loginImage} style={styles.image} />
            <View style={styles.SeparatorLine} />
            <Text style={styles.text}>
                Enter
            </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: Is your `Form` registered for navigation?

Comment: Yes. I also tried that. In my App.js file , I have added Form.js. However I am  using this Form.js as component not as screen

Comment: If your `Form.js` is a component try using the hoc wrapper for navigation as [this](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/with-navigation.html#docsNav) or pass the navigation props from parent file

Answer (score 2):

Well I found the solution I guess. Where I call the Form.js component, I simply added {...this.props} as props.

```
<Form {...this.props}   />
```

Like this because props of Form.js was empty.